# Filter by category in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have Laravel project, I want filter menu by products category I have in blade this select form which selects food dish how is it cold,hot or something

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">Product Type:</label>
         <select class="form-control" name="category" id="">
  @foreach ($variety as $cate)
<option value="{{ $cate->menu_categories }}">{{ $cate->menu_categories }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
</div>
```

In DB there are food categories: Hot Dish and Cold Dish, when I add it shows like this

```
<div class="container mt-3">
  <div class="row">
    @foreach ($uploadProducts as $item)
    <div class="col-sm-2 p-0 rounded border mr-2 mb-2 " style="background-color: #fff">
      <img src="{{ asset('storage/' . $item->image_upload) }}" alt="..." class="img-fluid rounded w-100">
      <p class="h5 text-center mt-2 mb-2">{{ $item->my_products }}</p>
      <p class="h6 text-center p-1">{{ $item->my_products_desc }}</p>
      <p class="h6 ml-3">
        <span class="border rounded mb-2" style="background-color: rgb(48, 225, 28);">{{ $item->full_price }}₾</span>
      </p>
    </div>
    @endforeach
  </div>
</div>
```

and what I add for example pizza which category is Hot dish its also shows in Cold Dish. I want what is cold dish added in cold dish and what is hot added in hot dish table how can I filter it ?

here is my controller

```
public function index() {

        $uploadProducts = Products::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

        $addProducts = AddProducts::all();
        $dishes = Dishes::all();

        $variety = MenuVariety::all();

        

    return view('Products.products', compact('uploadProducts','dishes','addProducts', 'variety'));

    }
```

Screenshot:[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsDQQ.png)

I try edit DB also edit controller, for me is important example how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make filters using the relationship between product and category So you should use whereHas

First, you have to send the ID of the categoy on which you want the use to filter on the client side

Here's an example code

```
$products= Product::whereHas('category', function($query){

  $query->where('id', $request->category_id);

})->get();
```

This is if each product has one category and the filter is based on one category

In the event that each product has more than one category, and to search in many categories, you must use the following

```
$products= Product::whereHas('categories', function($query){

  $query->whereIn('id', $request->categories_id);

})->get();
```

the cold dishes

```
$cold_dishes = Post::whereHas('categories', function($q) {
            $q->where('name', "cold dishes");
        })->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(6)->get();
```

the hot dishes

```
$hot_dishes = Post::whereHas('categories', function($q) {
            $q->where('name', "hot dishes");
        })->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(6)->get();
```

Comment: Can you see screenshot ?

Comment: You want to make two sections on the page. The first section is the cold dishes, and the second section is the hot dishes

I will update the previous comment read it again

Answer (score 0):

you can filter in the same method in the controller using `->when(condition, callback)`, this method apply some query only when the condition is `true`. The code should be something like this:

```
public function index(Request $request) {
   $uploadProducts = Products::query()
      ->when($request->filled('category'), function($query) use ($request){

         //Here apply your where condition, I assume you use the foreign key category_id on Product model (maybe belongsTo relation on MenuVariety)
         $query->where('category_id', $request->input('category'));
      })
      ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
      ->get();

   $addProducts = AddProducts::all();

   $dishes = Dishes::all();

   $variety = MenuVariety::all();

   return view('Products.products', compact('uploadProducts','dishes','addProducts', 'variety'));
}
```

now in the blade you should put the select in a "GET form":

```
                    <form action="{{ route('the-same-route-name-of-your-view') }}" method="get">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Product Type:</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="category" id="">
                                @foreach ($variety as $cate)
                                    <option value="{{ $cate->menu_categories }}"
                                        {{ request('category') == $cate->menu_categories ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                        {{ $cate->menu_categories }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Now you can add a button to submit the form or add script with JS to submit the form every time the select is change with a "change" event.
Don't forget to validate the form request.

Comment: see screenshot, it is not what I want

Comment: my bad, maybe you should list varieties with their products instead of just products.